# Как настроить тесты для .aab на Apach Cordova

Tags: android, apache, cordova

Разработчики на проекте написали проложение на Apache Cordova для android
На стадии альфа мы собирали ток *.apk файлы, сейчас для загрузки в стор мы генерим и подписываем .aab, но вопрос встал в том, что google play console слишком часто его отклоняют из-за

> "Требования к приложениям для всей семьи. Стабильность приложения."

Если тестировать .apk файл то, мы тестировали их на физ телефонах и все было гуд
Сейчас сомнения стоят в том, что .aab порченный, как это можно проверить?

Я на проекте в роли DevOps
Наш CI/CD выглядит так

```
build_image_aab:
  stage: build_image
  image: docker:19.03.12
  services:
    - docker:19.03.12-dind
  script:
    - mv $ENV .env
    - cp -r /home/gitlab-runner/signature $(pwd)/signature
    - sudo docker build -t krif/chi-aab:latest -f release/Dockerfile.aab .
    - container_id=$(sudo docker create rif/chi-aab:latest)
    - sudo docker cp $container_id:/app/mobileapp/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab ./chary.aab
    - sudo docker rm $container_id
    - sudo docker image prune -f
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./chary.aab
      - ./signature
  tags:
    - signature
    #- for_build_images
  only:
    refs:
      - main
      - release


signature_aab:
  stage: signature
  image: androidsdk/android-31  # Используем образ с Android SDK 30
  script:
    - java -version
    - apksigner sign --ks signatureapp --ks-key-alias chi_app --ks-pass pass:$store_pass --out siry.aab --min-sdk-version 21 chry.aab
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./siry.aab
  tags:
    - for_build_images
  needs:
    - build_image_aab
```

Comment: Что значит "порченый" aab? Из чего собираете, то и получается :) Смотрите отчеты по крешам в консоли и исправляйте баги, там насколько я помню и видео прилагается. Возможно вы тестите совсем не то, что гугл в авто-тестах.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja
Что такое "креши"?
Сможете привести мне примеры и направить меня на нуж топики и литературу?
Видео прилагается где?
Я совсем не понимаю в тесты и тд, но буду рад оплатить ваше время для настройки данного в моем проекте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изучите функционал консоли разработчика Google Play. Она предоставляет много полезных данных от пользователей и делает самостоятельное автоматическое тестирование каждого загруженного вами билда.

Вот здесь описано что такое Android Vitals (crash + ANR), как их оценивать и как они влияют на приложение в Google Play:
https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals

Дополнительно после загрузки каждого нового билда в Google Play запускается автоматический pre-launch report чтобы оценить качество этого билда.
Как его читать пишут здесь:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9844487?hl=en

К тесту на каждом устройстве прилагается видео, можно посмотреть что и как тестировалось.